# Nginx rtmp module restream to a dynamic address

Tags: nginx, rtmp

some streams like:

```
rtmp://mysite:3939/app/aaaaaa;bbbb
rtmp://mysite:3939/app/wewewe;ffff
rtmp://mysite:3939/app/zeiwew;uuuu
```

comes to my nginx. i want restream them to these addresses:

```
rtmp://localhost:1935/app/aaaaaa
rtmp://localhost:1935/app/wewewe
rtmp://localhost:1935/app/zeiwew
```

i have this rtmp config, but i can not use map to make destination address.
should i use $name variable? how? thanks for your help

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 3939;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;
        application app {
            live on;
            push rtmp://localhost:1935/app/;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, to use FFmpeg to pull and rename the stream:

```sh
ffmpeg -f flv -i rtmp://localhost:1935/app/bbbb \
  -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/app/aaaaaa
```

> Note: You could use the `on_publish` hook to start your FFmpeg process, or `exec` should also works.

It's very powerful pattern to process the stream, not only renaming the stream, but transcoding or forwarding to multiple servers, etc.

However it's a bit complex for introducing FFmpeg.